# Matplotlib order of the X axis is wrong

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to do a live graph with Python using Matplotlib ([following this exact tutorial](https://pythonprogramming.net/live-graphs-matplotlib-tutorial/)). But the order of the X axis is wrong in my code, as it begins in 1, goes to 10, then 11, then goes back to 2, 3, 4, 5...

I just copied the code and the numbers in the tutorial, but I am getting different results. Here is the graph it shows for me:

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import style

style.use('fivethirtyeight')

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

def animate(i):

    graph_data = open("animation_file.txt", 'r').read()
    lines = graph_data.split('\n')
    xs = []
    ys = []

    for line in lines:

        if len(line) > 1:

            x, y = line.split(',')
            xs.append(x)
            ys.append(y)
    ax1.clear()
    ax1.plot(xs, ys)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000)
plt.show()
```

And here is the "animation_file.txt":

```
1, 5
2, 3
3, 4
4, 7
5, 4
6, 3
7, 6
8, 7
9, 4
10,4
11, 2
```

Comment: You found some code on the internet and you don't know how it works?  Did you spend any time reading through the Matplotlib docs? Have you ruled out any parts of the code? What do you suspect is the problem and what did you do to validate that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are treating x and y values as strings whilst you should parse them as numbers:

```
xs.append(float(x))
ys.append(float(y))
```

Alternatively:

```
x, y = map(float, line.split(','))
```

Result:

[image: plot]

Comment: I found that it works correctly when the type of x-axis is int or float. But when the x-axis ticks is mixed with int and char, is there any proper way to get the right order? E.g. NN3, NN10, NN15 .... will be shown in the order of NN10, NN15, NN3 .... in the case of string-type and it cannot be converted into int if the ticks are not changed to int type.